# Fetched table data from a webpage not displaying first column of table

Tags: vba, excel

I need to fetch the price table from this page:
http://www.kieskeurig.nl/objectief/canon/ef_100mm_f2_usm/prijzen/bezorgen/167557#prijzen

So far I have developed this code to get the data

```
Sub TableExample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String

    strURL = "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/objectief/canon/ef_100mm_f2_usm/prijzen/bezorgen/167557#prijzen"

    ' replace with URL of your choice

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
         '.Visible = True
        .navigate strURL
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Set doc = IE.document
        GetAllTables doc

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub

Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

     ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                rng.Value = cl.innerText
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                I = I + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
            I = 0
        Next rw
    Next tbl

    ws.Cells.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

This code does work for me

But the problem is the 1st column i.e. the supplier data is not displaying in the fetched table.

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Which column's data is missing? I think your query is just fetching a blank table.

Comment: There is no mistake with your code. If by supplier data you mean the name of the shops/stores (ie. `cameranu.nl`, etc.), you have to find a way to get their `alt` tag values. Reason is, they're images. The only text in that cell is the ratings (ie. `9.0 (4509 reviews)`, etc.), which is why that's the only data you're scraping. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @BK201 yes that's what i mean...how can i get their alt tag values using this code.

Comment: @PankajJaju no this query is fetching the whole table but the shops/stores is not being fetched

Comment: @user3305327 - Yes ... I meant that it was fetching one extra blank column (Table 1). The stores are perhaps the icons which BK201 explained. Otherwise, I can see the data getting in excel nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `GetAllTables` subroutine with the following:

```
Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

     ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            colno = 1
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                If colno = 1 and nextrow > 1 then
                    Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("shopLogoX")
                    Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 2).getElementsByTagName("img")
                    rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")
                Else
                    rng.Value = cl.innerText
                End If
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                I = I + 1
                colno = colno + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
            I = 0
        Next rw
    Next tbl

    ws.Cells.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

The change is very little, actually. We use `colno` to track on which column we're in already in the row. Obviously, we check if we're in the first cell. If we are on the first column and not on the first row (header row), we create a collection of elements with class `shopLogoX`. This contains the `img` tags that have the `alt` attribute we want.

***Tried, tested, and working.*** Let us know if this helps.